# Windows 7 PC can't find Windows Vista PC

Tags: networking, windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-vista, wireless-networking

I have two PCs that connect through a wireless router,

- a Windows Vista Business Edition PC and
- a Windows 7 PC

The Windows Vista PC is able to find the Windows 7 PC in the Windows Explorer Network folder, but the Windows 7 PC cannot find the Windows Vista PC.

However, if I do a remote desktop connection from the Windows 7 PC I am able to connect to that Vista PC.  What are the settings needed to connect to the Vista PC from the Windows 7 network folder?

Comment: Any firewall active? Try temporarily disabling it and test again.

Answer (score 1):

Who knows how the Networking/Neighborhood folder works.  It sounds like your PCs can find each other but the Win 7 PC can't see the Vista PC.

I'd just to make sure the Vista PC has network discovery on and that the firewall isn't blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

Are both PCs member of same workgroup? If not, make them join or create a workgroup first, here's the instruction for [Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Join-or-create-a-workgroup) and here's for [Windows Vista](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Join-or-create-a-workgroup).

[image]

After rebooting both PCs, enable the Network Discovery, File Sharing etc options in -> Control Panel-> Network and Sharing Center -> Change advanced sharing settings(in the left pane) and you should be able to see PCs in network/network places in Windows Explorer.

Edit:: Aug-10

@user823527

regarding firewall settings, are (1) File and Printer Sharing and (2) HomeGroup allowed in your Windows 7 firewall ?

[image]

Comment: This was already done.  Both pc were in workgroup WORKGROUP with Network Discovery, File Sharing on.

Comment: If I turn off the firewall briefly on the Windows Vista PC, I am able to see that PC on Windows 7, but there are still security settings that prevent exploring that PC from the Network folder.  So what firewall settings would allow me to access the Vista computer from the Windows 7 computer.  Accessing the Windows 7 computer from Vista works.

Comment: File and printer sharing are allowed but homegroup isn't listed.